# Planes waves produced from an infinite current sheet

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

A uniform current sheet in free space is given to be, in phasor form, $\vec{J}=\vec{x}J_0e^{-jk_1y}$ located at the $z=0$ plane. $k_1 < k_0$ where $k_0$ is the wavenumber in free space.

The phasor form of the $\hat{x}$ component of the electric field I got had the term: $e^{-j(k_1 y + k_0z )}$.

Intuitively, the waves propagate in $+\hat{z}$ and $-\hat{z}$ directions, but the result above contradicts it.

Does this mean that the electric field also has a polarization in the $\hat{y}$ direction? What are some other implications of the constant $k_1$ for the EM waves that are being generated by it?

Comment: The current density does not depend upon time, so there is no electromagnetic wave. Can use Ampere's Law to determine the magnetic field.  Given ${\bf K} = K_0 \cos k_1y {\bf i}$ (from a notation point of view I prefer to use ${\bf K}$ for a surface current density and ${\bf J}$ for a volume current density). Using Ampere's Law you can find the magnitude of the magnetic field is given as $B=B(y) = \frac{\mu_0}{2} K(y)$.